# Scheduling shutdown with cron

Tags: cron

I want to use crond to shut down my system late at night in case I forget.

robin@robin-OptiPlex-780: crontab -l

30 1 * * * /sbin/shutdown > $HOME/cronlog/cron.log 2>&1

robin@robin-OptiPlex-780:cat $HOME/cronlog/cron.log

Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to call ScheduleShutdown in logind, no action will be taken: Interactive authentication required.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?
I'm running crontab -e from my user account (not root), Ubuntu 18.04
Robin.

Comment: Do you have any particular objection to running it as root (i.e. via `sudo crontab -e`)?

Comment: `shutdown` must be run with `sudo` or as `root`. If you use `crontab -e` the cronjob will run as the user `robin`. If you use `sudo crontab -e`. The cronjob will run as `root` and it will not ask for "interactive authentication".

Comment: Thanks. I was confused because I routinely run /sbin/shutdown from my user account and it works, so I supposed that cron jobs  initiated from crontab in my user account would work in the same way. It does indeed work when I use the root account, so problem solved - but still unsure as to why shutdown works from my user terminal. Robin.